# KVM problems with virt-install

Tags: linux, kvm, libvirt

Virt-install hangs. virt-install --name vm --memory 1024 --vcpus 1 --cdrom /rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-dvd.iso --os-variant rhel7 --disk none.
It doesn't metter if I create a new vm or import from qcow2.
Output:
Starting install...
Domain installation still in progress. Waiting for installation to complete.

After interrupting ctrl c the vm is created but there is no possibility to connect via console. Console is enabled but doesn't work. Is there any solution?